# Using an APA format, how do I report an F-statistic with a value of 2.67e+30?

Tags: regression, reporting, f-statistic

I am doing a statistical report on a regression model and my F-statistic is 2.67e+30. The values of my dependent and independent variables are expressed in dollars.

Comment: Do you are actually *need* to report the F statistic. I can't imagine a reader being interested in it at all, though knowing nothing about your model or domain I could obviously be wrong.  I assume you are sure that such a large statistic is not the result of an error ?

Comment: Why can't you report it just as 2.67e+30?

Comment: If it's that big, no-one should want to see more detail.

Comment: [Searching for "reporting large numbers in APA style"](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=reporting+large+numbers+in+APA+style&ia=web) yields hits like [this one](https://apastyle.apa.org/instructional-aids/numbers-statistics-guide.pdf), which in turn mentions Sections 6.32–6.35 in the APA Publication Manual. Have you checked there? That said, I would rather use the "mathematical" $2.67\times 10^{30}$ than the "engineering" $2.67e+30$.